# Why Hashmap is not displaying in order?

Tags: java, hashmap

Items displayed as unsorted 
        map.put("California", "Sacramento");
        map.put("Oregon", "Salem");
        map.put("Washington", "Olympia");
        System.out.println(map);

```
    map.put("Alaska", "Juneau");
    System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: why it should be displayed at the end?

Comment: This is a feature.  Consider using a TreeMap instead.

Answer (score 4):

HashMaps in java aren't sorted!

- HashMap makes absolutely no guarantees about the iteration order. It
  can (and will) even change completely when new elements are added.
- TreeMap will iterate according to the "natural ordering" of the keys
  according to their compareTo() method (or an externally supplied
  Comparator). Additionally, it implements the SortedMap interface,
  which contains methods that depend on this sort order.
- LinkedHashMap will iterate in the order in which the entries were put
  into the map

Answer (score 0):

I try it, my print is :

```
{California=Sacramento, Oregon=Salem, Washington=Olympia}
{California=Sacramento, Oregon=Salem, Washington=Olympia, Alaska=Juneau}
```

`Alaska=Juneau` is displayed at the end.

but TreeMap is order.print:

```
{Alaska=Juneau, California=Sacramento, Oregon=Salem, Washington=Olympia}
```